# How to get data from 2 tables via active record in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I can't understand the Rails Active Record logic.

I have 2 models:

- Wsdl
- Status

```rb
# wdsl
class Wsdl < ApplicationRecord
  has_one :status
  validates :mis_url, presence: true
  validates :short_name, presence: true
end

# status
class Status < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :wsdl
end
```

Tables in DataBase:
[image: tables in db]

I'm doing a simple SQL query via a program (not ActiveRecord and Rails), and as you can see, I have 9 columns in each record:

[image: sql query via program]

But, if I execute this query via Active Record I get an object with "3 columns" in each "record":

[image: active record sql query]

As you can see the queries are equal but I get data without the "Status" model.

PS I can't modify the "Wsdls" table in real - I really need the "Statuses" table and I don't want use a raw SQL query in Rails to get data from two tables.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Rails `.joins` is used primarily for applying conditions on the joined table:

```
Wsdl.joins(:status).where(statuses: { code: 99 })
```

Since this creates an inner join only rows from users that have a match in addresses will be returned.

You can also use `.joins` or `.left_joins` (Rails 5+) together with a custom select to select aggregates or columns from the joined table.

```
Wsdl.joins(:status).select('wsdl.*', 'status.code as status_code')

# Using a LEFT OUTER JOIN instead of INNER will return rows with no status
Wsdl.left_joins(:status).select('wsdl.*', 'status.code as status_code')
```

If you instead want to load model instances and avoid N+1 query issues use `.includes` or `.eager_load` instead. The difference is that `.eager_load` loads everything up front while `.includes` tries to be smart and load only if needed.

```
# This will load all the records and the assocation at once
@wsdls = Wsdl.eager_load(:status)
@wsdls.each do |object|
  # this would cause a N+1 query if we didn't eager load.
  puts object.status.code
end
```

Answer (score 3):

ActiveRecord relation `joins` is for writing complex queries, but model loads attributes only from its own table (unless you write something like `.select('statuses.code as attr_name_for_code, wsdls.*')`)

You can use `.joins(:status).includes(:status)` to eager load the association, rails will construct `select ... from ... join ...` with all fields from both models itself, and `wsdl.status` objects will already be loaded.